# can't print readAllStandardOutput correctly decoded

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qbytearray

I have this code to print into a text field all the output from a process:

```
data = self.m_process.readAllStandardOutput()
s = str(data)
self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.append(s)
```

What I get in the output is this:

```
b''
b''
b''
b'\r\nStarting "C:\\Program Files'
b''
b'\\Autodesk\\Maya2018\\bin\\mayabatch.exe"\r\n'
b'Initialized VP2.0 renderer {\r\r\n'
```

I'm not able to decode it and print it in the right way. I know that what comes from readAllStandardOutput is a QByteArray

Comment: python2 or python3? PyQt5 or PySide2? because it seems that you are using Maya and this executes PySide or PySide2 with python2 which influences the answer.

Comment: try changing `s = str(data)` to `s = data.decode()`

Comment: PyQt5 with Python3. data.decode() gives me error AttributeError: 'QByteArray' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) to string, first convert it to bytes using the [data()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data) method, and then [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to convert it to string:

```py
data = self.m_process.readAllStandardOutput()
s = data.data().decode() # <---
self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.append(s)
```

Another method is to convert the [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) to [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) and then use [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode):

```py
data = self.m_process.readAllStandardOutput()
s = bytearray(data).decode() # <---
self.m_ui.b_renderOutput.append(s)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, now I have a clean string. Last thing, do you know why I get random newlines in the output? Like:
O\n

penCL evaluator is attempting to initialize OpenCL.



D\n

etected 1 OpenCL Platforms:

Comment: @Hyperion Do not use append() since you insert an extra endline, instead use insertPlainText()